# Unable to run on iOS Simulator and iPhone

Tags: ios, gluon, gluon-mobile

I've followed the Gluon Mobile documentation and I was able to run the example on desktop using NetBeans 8.2.

When I execute the *launchPhoneSimulator* task the following appear on console (I've installed Xcode 8.2.1):

```
Executing: gradle :launchIPhoneSimulator

:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:createDefaultIOSLauncher UP-TO-DATE
:compileIosJava UP-TO-DATE
:processIosResources UP-TO-DATE
:iosClasses UP-TO-DATE
:iosExtractNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
:launchIPhoneSimulator FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launchIPhoneSimulator'.
> org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Command '/var/folders/k8/2n_6gyt11sg3j0y1rs_cq9yw90_n8s/T/ios-sim7848548085597099282 showdevicetypes' failed with output: 2017-01-25 10:25:29.090 ios-sim7848548085597099282[39624:2618148] +[SimDeviceSet defaultSet]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x105fff5b8
  2017-01-25 10:25:29.090 ios-sim7848548085597099282[39624:2618148] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[SimDeviceSet defaultSet]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x105fff5b8'
  *** First throw call stack:
  (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffbb41fe7b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fffcfffacad objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffbb4a1bf4 +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffbb391fb5 ___forwarding___ + 1061
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffbb391b08 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   ios-sim7848548085597099282          0x0000000101944c21 -[iPhoneSimulator showDeviceTypes] + 75
    6   ios-sim7848548085597099282          0x0000000101946dd1 -[iPhoneSimulator runWithArgc:argv:] + 3111
    7   ios-sim7848548085597099282          0x0000000101946fb9 main + 101
    8   ios-sim7848548085597099282          0x0000000101944150 start + 52
    9   ???                                 0x0000000000000002 0x0 + 2
  )
  libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (Exit value: 134)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 8.615 secs
```

When, instead, I try to run it my iPhone using the *launchIODevice* task, the following appear in console:

```
Executing: gradle :launchIOSDevice

:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:createDefaultIOSLauncher UP-TO-DATE
:compileIosJava UP-TO-DATE
:processIosResources UP-TO-DATE
:iosClasses UP-TO-DATE
:iosExtractNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
:launchIOSDevice FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launchIOSDevice'.
> No provisioning profile found matching signing identity 'iPhone Developer: music@adregulamartis.it (5MQZC923QJ)' and app bundle ID 'com.gluonsingleview.GluonSingleView'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.848 secs
```

What I've missing?

Comment: What is your jfxmobile plugin version? Update it to 1.3.2 if lower, and try again

Comment: Thank you, this solved partially the problem.
I still have the following issues:
1. How can I choose the iPad/iPhone simulators to be used?

Comment: 2. I'm still unable to run on my real iPhone. The following Message appear:

`No provisioning profile found matching signing identity 'iPhone Developer: music@adregulamartis.it (5MQZC923QJ)' and app bundle ID 'com.gluonsingleview.GluonSingleView'`

What is a "provisioning profile"? How can I add it to my iPhone? Where is the documentation related to this issue?

Comment: You can find doumentation [here](http://docs.gluonhq.com/javafxports/#_ios_4) and [here](http://docs.gluonhq.com/javafxports/#_building_and_running)